# Creating vista style controls in .NET

Tags: .net, windows-vista

OK I would like to know this once and for all, how can I create "vista-style" controls from within .NET? I am using .NET 3.5 SP1.

The most important control I am attempting to spawn is the new enhanced message dialog which looks like this:
[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Aa511268.Dialogs23a(en-us,MSDN.10).png](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Aa511268.Dialogs23a(en-us,MSDN.10).png)

I am attempting to follow guidelines laid down here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511268.aspx) but I find Microsoft is very good at laying down the guidelines, but not with explaining how to use or access these.

Any information on how to create the message dialog and the plethora of other controls which are new to vista would be greatly appreciated.  I would also be interested to know how Windows XP reacts if you attempt to spawn one of these controls.

I am aware of one control named `TaskDialog` but again I do not know how to get started with using this in .NET and to my knowledge, it is not the control in use in the screenshot.

**Update: After further research, I believe TaskDialog might be what I am after - does anybody have code samples of this running within .NET?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the really cool dialogs like provided in the UAC you need to some native calls.  www.pinvoke.net is a great resource for this information.

**Update: These are all really [good examples for TaskDialog](http://www.google.com/search?q=taskdialog+vista+example).**

Comment: Thanks dude after I posted I also found the "API in Managed Code" one, looks great, and www.wintaskdialog.com also looks good and the difference there is they draw a vista 'mock' dialog if you are on XP or lower, which is kinda nice.  But you pay for it of course.

Comment: Just to let everyone know which one I went with: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/Vista_TaskDialog_Wrapper.aspx.  Simple, elegant and lightweight which is important for WinXP emulation when included in other apps.